# Posting about data sets

Tags: discussion, data-request

If I learn about a public data set that others might find interesting, how should I let others know?  Should I ask a question, such as, "Is anyone looking for outbreak data"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go ahead and post a "question", and then answer it yourself. For example, "Where can I find outbreak data... related to ... ?"

Here is a recent question that was self-answered: [Graph of Landsat Downloads](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4370/1511)

The meta-stackexchange site has [an interesting discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/254520).

Comment: Posting data that's not open but requires purchase?

Answer (score 6):

If it is a portal site, you can post the site to our crowd-sourced catalog of open data portals. There are about 1450 sites cataloged currently.

http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/

Comment: Both answers are helpful.  It's too bad only 1 of them can be "accepted".

Answer (score 2):

this is where having a wiki to go along with the forum would be killer. something along the lines of r/datasets on reddit. considering there isn't one here yet, i would post the new datasets there:
https://reddit.com/r/datasets

Answer (score 1):

If it's research data, I'd also suggest submitting a listing for the archive/repository at [re3data](http://www.re3data.org/), the Registry of Research Repositories.